# How to install two Android application with same package name

Tags: android

I have created an application just like Careem or Uber. I have very little knowledge of Android development at the start of building this app. I created only one application but later I know that I have to develop two separate application. Then I copy one application as original and developed two applications separately.

These two applications working perfectly on multiple devices according to requirement but the issue is that I am not able to install both application simultaneously on the device. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: You can't. Each app must have it's own unique package. If you want to install both apps in one device then change package name of one of the app

Comment: If I change applicationId in build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, Use this guide to change package name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio

Comment: If you are using services like `Firebase` you will have change library specific files too ex `Google-service.json` in case of `Firebase`

Comment: That is the problem I am getting now. Because I want to add both these application to firebase for push notification. Both these application have same package. Now kindly guide me what can I do

Comment: Open Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> General -> Your Apps -> Add your other app here and update new  `google-services.json` in your android project

Comment: Kindly provide me step by step detail to change package name of one of the app as suggested in your first comment

Comment: Go through the link I provided earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio

Comment: Got It. Done!!!

Comment: You could have done it with something called flavours of android https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your build.gradle you can set your applicationId. Choose a different applicationId for each app and you can install both on the same phone.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Comment: Got it. I am confusing app id with package name

Comment: I am trying to add these application in Firebase Console, as these application have same  package name. What can I do now?

Comment: you can't do any thing firebase not allowed to those app who have same package name your to change the package name for other

Comment: Change you applicationId in your build.gradle file. then go to your firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com) then go to your existing project. And create a new app by clicking "+ Add app" fill in you new packagename (applicationId) -> download google-services.json and add this to your android project with the updated packageName (applicationId). That should be it.

Comment: You do not need to change your projects package structure.